# PXE Won't boot with new version of Boot agent

Tags: windows-server-2012, nic, wds

We are running WDS on server2012 and it's doing fine with older machines. But we bought new stack of HP's with Intel i217-lm NIC, it is using Boot agent GE v.1.5.50.
When we are trying to boot it gets ip via dhcp, but  ends with error:
PXE-E55: ProxyDHCP service did not reply to request on port 4011

I tried to change dhcp scope options by MS recommendations:

```
Option 60= PXEClient
Option 66= WDS server name or IP address
Option 67= Boot file name
```

Any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround was booting from network in UEFI mode. There is limitations regarding new Intel's boot agent

Answer (score 0):

To see if the DHCP process is where the problem lies, one test to try is running Wireshark on the DHCP server to see if the packet was received by the server, and if the server sent the packet back to the i217 adapter.

If the packet reached the DHCP server but didn't get sent back maybe it is a firewall issue. I would also check the IP address leases and make sure everything looks error-free (ie no duplicate IPs, bad addresses).

Also if you want to verify that there are not known PXE issues with the i217 adapters, or if there any quirks, you can ask the Wired Ethernet blog at communities.intel.com about the issue you're seeing. They usually have someone who can help from Intel on there.